# URL in heroCard does not open a new browser window

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We have a node js based app for message extension.
For the text param of the hero card we provide an  with an URL in href.
In the chat or group chat, clicking the url does not open a new browser tab.
When we do the same thing in a team post the url opens a new tab.

We want the url in the card to open a new browser tab also in a chat and a group chat.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please share that after sending card it's not working or when it's in preview in compose box area then it's not working?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT, both the situations. It is not working in the preview and also after the card is send in a message.

Comment: For preview its by design behaviour. OpenURL won't work in preview. But it should work after card has sent. Could you please share your card Json to test at our end and could you please confirm that if you are using action based messaging extension or search based messaging extension?

Comment: We have added messaging extension and displayed the herocard. In herocard in text we have added the href tag. But at our end the URL is opening in chat and group chat.

Comment: At our end the URL is opening in chat and group chat.
We have tested this in web and desktop Teams client Version 1.5.00.35276 (64-bit).

Comment: Please have a look for following video: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/92150070/209435687-71aed177-bdb9-412e-a8ea-5effa0558cfe.mp4